# Installing Printers with .INF in Windows x64 and NSIS

Tags: windows, 64-bit, nsis, drivers, printers

I create an Installer, with two printers netowrk with CUPS.

In Windows x86 (32 bits), the printers are installed without problems, with driver, and all ok.

But the problem is when i run the .exe in x64, i can detect the Arquitecture, i put the x64.nsh in the top, but not function the command.

The message is "Driver Invalid"

I check the Driver and is x64 Driver...

I use **ExecWait: rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry ...** with corresponent name, .inf...

Anyone can help me with the problem to Install x64 Printers with Nsis installer?

Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ExecWait '"$WinDir\SysNative\RunDll32.exe" printui.dll PrintUIEntry ...'` on x64? (Will not work on 32-bit systems so you need to check with `x64.nsh` to see which RunDll32 path you want, on 32-bit you just need `"$SysDir\RunDll32.exe"`)

Comment: Hello Anders. Thank you for your reply.

The program detect without problem the arquitecture (x86 / x64).

In x86 not have any problem, install the printer with the correspondent Driver (.INF) without problem, but if the Windows is x64, all is the same as x86, but appear the "Driver incompatible", and not install the printer in x64.

Tomorrow I try your solution, but now, the line is:

x86 -> ExecWait: rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry '"/m ""Name Printer" /f "File.INF" /r "URL Of Printer"'

In x86, the lines works fine, but in x64, give me "Driver incompatible".

Thanks for all!

Comment: I need install Printer with corresponent Driver... in x86 works fine, but in x64... not find the correct form to install :(

Comment: Hello friend! In Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7, all OK with x86 and x64, but in Windows 8 appear the message "Driver not compatible". Thanks.

Comment: Can you just try to use the code I posted? I don't know if it will work but I suspect the process needs to be 64-bit to install a 64-bit driver...

Comment: Hello friend, the line is this: ExecWait 'rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /b "Ricoh MP 7500" /x /n "Ricoh MP 7500" /h "x86" /if /f "OEMSETUP.INF" /r "http://localhost:631/printers/Ricoh_MP_7500" /m "RICOH Aficio MP 7500 PCL 6"'.

This line works OK in Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7, with x86 and x64. But when execute this line in Windows 8, appear the message "Driver incorrect". Thanks for all! ;)

Comment: In your question you said the problem was on all versions of x64 and now it is just Windows 8 64-bit?

Comment: Last Friday give me error, but today, i worked in the office this morning and can Install in Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7, with x86 and x64. Now... the error only is in the Windows 8, and give the error "Driver incompatible". // The line is: ExecWait 'rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /b "Ricoh MP 7500" /x /n "Ricoh MP 7500" /h "x86" /if /f "OEMSETUP.INF" /r "http://localhost:631/printers/Ricoh_MP_7500"; /m "RICOH Aficio MP 7500 PCL 6"'. You have any form to install Printer in Windows 8 x64 with corresponent .inf? Thanks for all! ;)